# Javascript unload page condition

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code to prompt the user that if he left the page he can't come back. Things happened that i want to redirect the page using setTimeout function after a specific time. I want to disable checking for user leaving the page when the automatic redirection starts.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        needToConfirm = true;
        window.onbeforeunload = askConfirm;

        function askConfirm(){
            if (needToConfirm){
                return "Please note that you might not be able to come back and watch the movie again.";
                }
            }
    </script>
```

Comment: The `language` attribute of the `script` element is [deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html#edef-SCRIPT).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unset `onbeforeunload` in the function called by `setTimeout` before you redirect the user:

```
window.onbeforeunload = null;
```