# Detect when user navigates away from page

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I detect that a user is navigating away from my page?
Kind of like stackoverflow does, if you have started writing a post.

I have tried `$(window).unload()` in jQuery, but I can't get it to work.

This statement is not entirely true, in IE9 it works, in fact a bit too well. It also pops up, if the page is refreshed.
But in Chrome, nothing triggers.

Comment: look at this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032249/javascript-unload-page-condition

Comment: Also here: http://kbeezie.com/cross-browser-exit-pop/

Comment: @Roysvork, that seems to work for me! Care you to submit an answer?

Comment: There is an excellent article on the matter here: http://kbeezie.com/cross-browser-exit-pop This explains all the ins and outs of the different browsers. Enjoy!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Include the jQuery library in your code, and then try out this

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){

        return 'DataTest';
});​
```

[**JsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3zR5r/2/)

Comment: It's funny, the JsFiddle demo works fine in my chrome browser, but if I implement on my page, it does nothing.

Comment: @Nicolai - check might be you fissing jquery file reference in page ...it will work for sure..

Comment: Yea, I have a ton of jquery on the page already, that works. It's weird.

Comment: Yea, unfortunately this didn't do anything for me. It works in IE, but for some reason not in chrome.

Comment: @Nicolai it's a known bug https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=501292